# Can I enable searching for partial strings?

Tags: 2013, list, search

We have a list which contains information about people (first name, last name, email address etc). The problem is search it.

When someone searches for "Smith" all the results appear as expected. However if someone searches for "Smit" or "mith" nothing appears.

Answer (score 5):

Suffix wildcard matching is supported in SharePoint. You can use "Smit*" but not "*mith".